# Given a relationship id, get the entry_id of related entries

Tags: relationships

I have a safecracker form for a channel which has a gender field.

The gender field is a relationship field that points to a gender channel.

Since I have the gender relationship id available to me via the {gender} tag in the safecracker form, how do I get the entry id of the gender channel row using it?

I am using EE 2.5.5

Comment: How are you trying to use the entry ID? Depending on usage I can think of a couple ways to get to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could just use `{field:gender}`, which will give you your Gender menu with the existing selection pre-selected.

But to answer your question, here's the query you would use (in 2.5.5 or lower - things change in 2.6+):

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT rel_child_id FROM exp_relationships WHERE rel_id = {gender}"}
     {rel_child_id}
{/exp:query}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in EE 2.6+?